# Crop content from document and scale cropped area to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

My objective on this one is to be able to crop any part of the html document (the image, the white background) and to be able to scale that same cropped area to the red square in the bottom of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WK6NX/). It's the final step to build a snipping tool (this is merely an experiment with web tools) and I am in need of a final push now, I can't seem to solve this properly without use of existent repositories. I could do this but it wouldn't be the point of trying after all. Any help, idea? Feel free to edit the fiddle ofc

**HTML**

```
<div id="selection_box"></div>
<img src="http://popcultureblog.dallasnews.com/files/2012/10/NORAH1BYNOAHABRAMS_27933966.jpeg" id="image_box">
<div id="captured_box"></div>
```

**JavaSctipt**

```
function getCursorPosition(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e) {
        if (e.pageX || e.pageX == 0) return [e.pageX, e.pageY];
        var dE = document.documentElement || {};
        var dB = document.body || {};
        if ((e.clientX || e.clientX == 0) && ((dB.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft == 0) || (dE.clientLeft || dE.clientLeft == 0))) return [e.clientX + (dE.scrollLeft || dB.scrollLeft || 0) - (dE.clientLeft || 0), e.clientY + (dE.scrollTop || dB.scrollTop || 0) - (dE.clientTop || 0)];
    }
    return null;
}

function mousedown(e) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
    var box = document.getElementById("selection_box");
    box.orig_x = mxy[0];
    box.orig_y = mxy[1];
    box.style.left = mxy[0] + "px";
    box.style.top = mxy[1] + "px";
    box.style.display = "block";
    document.onmousemove = mousemove;
    document.onmouseup = mouseup;
}

function mousemove(e) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
    var box = document.getElementById("selection_box");
    box.style.width = (mxy[0] - box.orig_x) + "px";
    box.style.height = (mxy[1] - box.orig_y) + "px";
}

function mouseup(e) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e),
        box = document.getElementById("selection_box"),
        image_box = document.getElementById("image_box"),
        selection = getSelection;
    box.style.display = "none";
    box.style.width = "0";
    box.style.height = "0";
    document.onmousemove = function () {};
    document.onmouseup = function () {};
}



document.onmousedown = mousedown;
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
#selection_box {
    -webkit-animation: blackwhite 3s infinite;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed #000000;
    background: transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blackwhite {
    40% {
        border-color:white;
    }
    100% {
        border-color:black;
    }
}
#image_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 370px;
}
#captured_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Always post the relative code on your post. You are not allowed to post a link to jsfiddle w/o code for a reason. If your fiddle gets deleted there would be no future reference for your code.

Comment: Just use [CSS transform](http://www.css3files.com/transform/) with `scale` to fit to the required box size?

Comment: The point here is that I'm lacking the ability to understand how should I keep the coords of the selection area, "copy" that particular content and then translate it to a totally different div...

Comment: Does the solution need to work on all major browsers? Firefox has a way to mirror elements, but it's the only browser that supports the feature.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problems of your realisation(here the mouse can go also to left and up from the click point.)

```
    function mousemove(e) {
    var mxy = getCursorPosition(e);
    var box = document.getElementById("selection_box");
    var right=mxy[0]>box.orig_x;
    var left=!right;
    var up=mxy[1]<box.orig_y;
    var down=!up;


    if(up &&  right){
    box.style.top = mxy[1] + "px";
    }

    else if(up && left){
    box.style.left = mxy[0] + "px";
    box.style.top = mxy[1] + "px";
    }

    else if(down && left){
    box.style.left = mxy[0] + "px";
    box.style.top = mxy[1] - "px";
    }

    box.style.width = (Math.abs(mxy[0] - box.orig_x)) + "px";
    box.style.height = (Math.abs(mxy[1] - box.orig_y)) + "px";
}
```